# Codename one calendar issue

Tags: java, android, calendar, codenameone

**How can I use following methods with Codename one calendar.**

```
protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int currentMonth, int day);
protected Button createDay();
```

Comment: Why do you want to "use" these methods?  Do you want to call them, or override them to change how they work?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own Class and override this method as shown in below code

```
 class OwnCalendar extends Calendar{

            @Override
            protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int currentMonth, int day) {
// add your code
               // super.updateButtonDayDate(dayButton, currentMonth, day); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }


        }
```